# data.head() not displaying data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a Uber data analysis project. When I copy the first line of code the data frame does not appear.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\goonb\Downloads\Python\Projects\Uber\uber-raw-data-sep14.csv')
df["Date/Time"] = df["Date/Time"].map(pd.to_datetime)
df.head()
```

Comment: Try `print(df.head())` instead of just `df.head()`

Comment: Also you should change `df["Date/Time"] = df["Date/Time"].map(pd.to_datetime)` to `df["Date/Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date/Time"])`. It will be faster.

Comment: @user17242583 Actually passing `parse_dates=['Date/Time']` to `read_csv` would be better IMHO.

Comment: Yes, that would be even better. :)

Comment: this most likely has nothing to do with pandas, you don't have a file object in your path or its poorly formatted